# Figuring out obscure pointer typedef

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef solution_type (*algorithm_ptr_type) (
    problem_type problem,
    void (*post_evaluation_callback)(void *move, int score)/* = NULL*/
);
```

Please help me! Thank you

Comment: It means someone thought it would be fun to write an unmaintainable line of code.

Comment: I hear [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) just got an upgrade. Maybe something worth considering if you're being asked to maintain code like that...

Comment: Is it C or C++? They're not the same thing

Comment: @RafeKettler: In this context, they're the same thing. You dont have two different answers to this question. What applies to one, applies to other as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This means, `algorithm_ptr_type` is a pointer to a function returning `solution_type` and whose parameters are:

- *problem* of type `problem_type`
- `post_evaluation_callback`  which is again a function pointer taking two parameters (`void*` and `int`) , and returning `void`.

---

And the same can be written as (**easy and readable syntax**):

```
typedef  void (*callback_type)(void *move, int score);

typedef solution_type (*algorithm_type)(problem_type, callback_type);
```

**Note: the name of the parameters are optional, so I removed it, to make the typedef short and cute!**

---

In C++11, this can be simplified further as follows:

```
using algorithm_ptr_type = solution_type (*) (
    problem_type, 
    void(*)(void*, int)
);
```

That is much better, as now it's clear as to *what is being defined* and in terms of *what*.

---

In C++11, you can even define a utility to create function-pointer as,

```
//first define a utility to make function pointer.
template<typename Return, typename ... Parameters>
using make_fn = Return (*)(Paramaters...);
```

then use it as,

```
using callback_type = make_fn<void, void*, int>;

using algorithm_type = make_fn<solution_type, problem_type, callback_type>;
```

Here the first argument to `make_fn` is the return type, and the rest are the parameters — easy to decipher each one!

---

**Usage:**

```
solution_type SomeFunction(problem_type problem, callback post_evaluation)
{
   //implementation

   //call the callback function
   post_evaluation(arg1, arg2);
   //..
}

algorithm_ptr_type function = SomeFunction;

//call the function
function(arg, someOtherFunction);
```

Comment: There are no functions in the code in question:  there is a pointer-to-function type (named `algorithm_ptr_type`) and a pointer-to-function parameter (named `post_evaluation_callback`).

Comment: @Andy: I explained the usage as well. Please see it!

Answer (score 5):

what a horrible piece of code!

what its doing is defining a function pointer type called `algorithm_ptr_type`, returning a `solution_type` and taking a `problem_type` as its first arg and a callback as its second arg. the callback takes `void*` and `int` as its args and returns nothing.

a better way to write this would be:

```
typedef void (*post_evaluation_callback)(void *move, int  score);
typedef solution_type (*algorithm_ptr_type)(problem_type problem, post_evaluation_callback callback);
```

Comment: `post_evaluation_callback` doesn't return `solution_type`. It returns `void`....`algorithm_ptr_type` returns `solution_type`.

Answer (score 2):

This frustrating piece of code makes it so that `algorithm_ptr_type` is a function pointer.

This type must point to a function that returns an object of type `solution_type`.
This type must point to a function that takes the following arguments:
0: An object of type problem_type.
1: A function pointer which must point to a function that:
Returns void.
Takes the following arguments:
0: A `void*`.
1: An `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Defines solution_type as a function pointer to a function that takes a problem_type and another function pointer. This second function pointer takes a void* (anything) and an int as parameters.

Comment: Actually, solution_type is the return type, not the function pointer.